# Instead-of-insert trigger for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

For a logging system I want to have the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [App]      NVARCHAR (30)  NULL,
    [Source]   NVARCHAR (30)  NULL,
    [LogLevel] NVARCHAR (5)   NULL,
    [Logger]   NVARCHAR (120) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Categories] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([App] ASC, [Source] ASC, [LogLevel] ASC, [Logger] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Occurences] (
    [PointInTime] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]  INT    NOT NULL,
    [Noise]       INT    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Occurences] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PointInTime] ASC, [CategoryId] ASC, [Noise] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id])
);
```

The design goal is to allow for a large amount of logging data as the more expensive strings are factored out in a separate table.

Semantically, both tables form a single logical table defined by this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[HistoricLogEntries]
    AS SELECT o.PointInTime, o.Noise, c.App, c.[Source], c.LogLevel, c.Logger
    FROM Occurences o
    JOIN Categories c ON o.CategoryId = c.Id;
```

I'd now like to define an instead-of-insert-trigger on the view, which is where my troubles start. I have the following attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on [dbo].[HistoricLogEntries]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Categories
    SELECT i.App, i.[Source], i.LogLevel, i.Logger
    FROM INSERTED i;

    INSERT INTO Occurences
    SELECT i.PointInTime, i.Noise, c.Id AS CategoryId
    FROM INSERTED i
    JOIN Categories c ON i.App = c.App AND i.[Source] = c.[Source] AND i.LogLevel = c.LogLevel AND i.Logger = c.Logger;
END
```

There is the obvious first problem that the first insert isn't checking whether the tuple is already in the database. I'd know how to do that in the case of a single value insert, but here I have to account for a multiple row insert.

Another thing that I can't explain is that the trigger doesn't even work in case the first insert succeeds. I get a foreign key violation - as if the first insert didn't actually insert anything.

I thought this should be a common setup, so maybe someone has some similar example code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For SQL2008+ I would use MERGE statement to insert new categories:

```
MERGE dbo.Categories WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS c
USING INSERTED AS i ON i.App = c.App
AND i.[Source] = c.[Source]
AND i.LogLevel = c.LogLevel
AND i.Logger = c.Logger
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (App, [Source], LogLevel, Logger)
    VALUES (i.App, i.[Source], i.LogLevel, i.Logger);
```

I used `HOLDLOCK` table hint [to prevent race condition](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx):

> [...] To prevent concurrent sessions from inserting data with the same
>   key, an incompatible lock must be acquired to ensure only one session
>   can read the key (my note: UK_Categories unique index in this case) and that lock must be held until the transaction
>   completes.[...]

And to prevent FK errors:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Category". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.
```

I would add the the name of every column within second `INSERT` thus:

```
INSERT INTO Occurences (PointInTime, Noise, CategoryId)
SELECT i.PointInTime, i.Noise, c.Id AS CategoryId
FROM INSERTED i
JOIN Categories c ON i.App = c.App
```

The reason of these FK errors is an inconsistency within order of columns:

1) The order of column within CREATE TABLE is

```
   [PointInTime] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]  INT    NOT NULL,
    [Noise]       INT    NOT NULL,
```

but

2) Within second insert the order of columns is different (see CategoryId vs Noise):

```
INSERT INTO Occurences
-- or INSERT INTO Occurences (PointInTime, CategoryId, Noise)
SELECT i.PointInTime, i.Noise, c.Id AS CategoryId
FROM ...
```

This is the my solution:

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on [dbo].[HistoricLogEntries]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN       
    MERGE dbo.Categories WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS c
    USING INSERTED AS i ON i.App = c.App
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (App)
        VALUES (i.App);

    INSERT INTO Occurences (PointInTime, Noise, CategoryId)
    SELECT i.PointInTime, i.Noise, c.Id AS CategoryId
    FROM INSERTED i
    JOIN Categories c ON i.App = c.App
END
GO
```

Comment: That's really comprehensive, and so quickly after I posted the question. Thank you very much!